# "Unable to read data" when converting stringUrl to image

Tags: ios, swift, image, url, download

I have a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell and I have images url in my buffer and I want to download and show the image in my CollectionView.

But don't know why It is showing unable to read data.
Here below is my code :-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BrandImagesCell", for: indexPath) as! BrandImagesCell

    //let StrUrl = NSURL(string: self.arrImages[indexPath.row])! as URL
    let urlPath: String = self.arrImages[indexPath.row]
    let StrUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

    cell.brandImage.downloadedFrom(url: StrUrl as URL, contentMode: .scaleToFill)

    return cell
}
```

And Method to download image :-

```
extension UIImageView {
func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    contentMode = mode
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
            self.image = image
        }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I have all images url in my array(self.arrImages).
What should I do to download show it in collectionView ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the error that you are seeing on the console ?

Comment: Using a lib like `SDWebImage` is much easier, this seems easy, but it actually pretty complex things, especially when combine with collection view, cant even tell all the things that can be error here

Comment: I have mentioned it @Sri

Comment: @Tj3n What to do?

Comment: post the URL of sample image for which you are facing problem

Comment: Please try these (as i cannot debug remote)

(1) Ensure `'App Transport Security Settings' (info.plist)` is not blocking, if the url is a http.
(2) ensure the url has images.
(3) try using a library like `Alamofire` for your network call to download image (or) using library like `SDWebImage`

Comment: I have Done this   
'App Transport Security Settings'  .

 .
thanks